# How to add Faded Border in ImageView which is Inside CollapsingToolbar?

Tags: android, user-interface, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I was trying to add a faded border to my ImageView which is present in CollapsingToolbarLayout, but I failed.

What I achieved is present in Image below

[image]

What I want to Achieve is 

[image]

The code I've tried is just a simple collapsing toolbar

```
           <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
               android:id="@+id/collapsing_detail_buddhism"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
               app:title=""
               app:expandedTitleMarginStart="10dp"
               app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
               app:expandedTitleMarginTop="20dp"
               app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1">

               <RelativeLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent">

                   <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/main_image"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="220dp"
                       android:src="@drawable/buddha"
                       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                       android:foreground="@drawable/drawable_bottom_effect"
                       />

               </RelativeLayout>

               <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                   android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail_buddhism"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                   app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


           </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Drawable code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:startColor="#00000000"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: So you don't want border?

Comment: No, you can see in the second image how I want the output to be.

Comment: You want white border instead of black?

Comment: You can see it's like a dark black border at bottom (in the first image) but in case of the second image the border is fading I want to achieve the same effect as the second image.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the fading of the `ImageView`, you can add a library called [FadingEdgeLayout](https://github.com/bosphere/Android-FadingEdgeLayout) to your layout.

1. Add `FadingEdgeLayout` to your project in `build.gradle`

> ```
> implementation
> 'com.github.bosphere.android-fadingedgelayout:fadingedgelayout:1.0.0'
> ```

2. After doing that, add the FadingEdgeLayout to your layout as follows:

> ```
> <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout 
>     android:id="@+id/collapsing_detail_buddhism"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
>     app:title=""
>     app:expandedTitleMarginStart="10dp"
>     app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
>     app:expandedTitleMarginTop="20dp"
>     app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
>     >
>
>     <com.bosphere.fadingedgelayout.FadingEdgeLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         app:fel_edge="bottom"
>         >
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/main_image"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="220dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/stories_background"
>             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
>             />
>
>     </com.bosphere.fadingedgelayout.FadingEdgeLayout>
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail_buddhism"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
>         app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
>
>
> </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
> ```

3. Changing your layout to above will add fading edge to your `ImageView`.
4. But keep in mind, `FadingEdgeLayout` takes the color of the background as color of the faded edge, so I've added `android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"` so you'll notice what color it takes for it's edges.
5. You can also add more edges(bottom,left,top,right), control the size of the fade, etc. Go on the link mentioned on the top of the answer.